# why void method1(T obj) is not allowed generics?

Tags: java, generics

when i do

```
 public class TestClass {
// i have intentionally not used TestClass<T>

   void method1(T obj){
// i know i can use Object instead of T but i am not getting why T is not allowed here?  
 }
```

Compile time exception is

```
 T cannot be resolved to a type
```

When i do this, it does not given any exception. How come T is resolved now ?

```
<T>T method1(T obj){
         return null;
     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type is not the issue, the generic specification (`<T>`) is.

In the first snipped you showed, the compiler has no way of knowing `T` is supposed to be a generic specifier, so it assumes it's a name of a class (like `Integer` or `String`). Since there is no such class, the compilation fails.

Once you add `<T>` at the beginning, it becomes clear that `T` is a generic specifier. Now, if you wish, you can change the return type to `void`:

```
<T> void method1 (T obj) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @ Mureinik. You almost answered my question. Don't you think it would have been better if jvm would have allowed void method1 (<T>T obj) than <T> void method1 (T obj). Just a thought